# How to put a bar in the margin beside a portion of text in a paragraph

Tags: margins, mdframed

I want to indicate only part of the text in a paragraph using a bar in the left margin. I would like to have something like the below example but without line breaks, and the text wrapping as though siderules wasn't there.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\newmdenv[
  topline=false,
  bottomline=false,
  rightline=false,
  skipabove=\topsep,
  skipbelow=\topsep,
  leftmargin=-10pt,
  rightmargin=-10pt,
  innertopmargin=0pt,
  innerbottommargin=0pt
]{siderules}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\begin{siderules}
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
\end{siderules}
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\end{document}
```

Comment: The easy way would be to use \tikzmark and tikzpagenodes, together with everypage.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\newcounter{tmp}
\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{%
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

\newcommand\StartRule{%
  \stepcounter{tmp}%
  \tikzmark{a}\label{a\thetmp}%
  \ifnum\getpagerefnumber{a\thetmp}=\getpagerefnumber{b\thetmp} \else
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \draw[ultra thick,gray]
      ([xshift=-10pt,yshift=1.5ex]a-|current page text area.west) --  ([xshift=-10pt]current page text area.south west);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \fi%
}

\newcommand\EndRule{%
\tikzmark{b}\label{b\thetmp}
  \ifnum\getpagerefnumber{a\thetmp}=\getpagerefnumber{b\thetmp}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \draw [ultra thick,gray]
      ([xshift=-10pt,yshift=1.5ex]a-|current page text area.west) -- ([xshift=-10pt]b-|current page text area.west);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \else
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \draw [ultra thick,gray]
      ([xshift=-10pt]current page text area.north west) -- ([xshift=-10pt]b-|current page text area.west);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \fi
}

\newcommand\LRule[1]{\StartRule#1\EndRule}

\begin{document}

Some test text and here we add some more text just for the example with some more words some more text just for the example with some more words some more text just for the example \StartRule and here we add some more text just for the example with some more words some more text just for the example with some more words some more text just for the example with some more words some more text just for the example with some more words \EndRule and here we add some more text just for the example with some more words some more text just for the example with some more words some more text just for the example and here we add some more text just for the example with some more words some more text just for the example with some more words some more text just for the example

\end{document}
```

[image]

Use `\StartRule <text>\EndRule` or `\LRule{<text>}`. It admits page breaks.

## Update

It works with `wrapfig`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\newcounter{tmp}
\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{%
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

\newcommand\StartRule{%
  \stepcounter{tmp}%
  \tikzmark{a}\label{a\thetmp}%
  \ifnum\getpagerefnumber{a\thetmp}=\getpagerefnumber{b\thetmp} \else
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \draw[ultra thick,gray]
      ([xshift=-10pt,yshift=1.5ex]a-|current page text area.west) --  ([xshift=-10pt]current page text area.south west);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \fi%
}

\newcommand\EndRule{%
\tikzmark{b}\label{b\thetmp}
  \ifnum\getpagerefnumber{a\thetmp}=\getpagerefnumber{b\thetmp}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \draw [ultra thick,gray]
      ([xshift=-10pt,yshift=1.5ex]a-|current page text area.west) -- ([xshift=-10pt]b-|current page text area.west);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \else
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \draw [ultra thick,gray]
      ([xshift=-10pt]current page text area.north west) -- ([xshift=-10pt]b-|current page text area.west);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \fi
}

\newcommand\LRule[1]{\StartRule#1\EndRule}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{.4\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{wrapfigure}
Some test text and here we add some more text just for the example with some more words some more text just for the example with some more words some more text just for the example \StartRule and here we add some more text just for the example with some more words some more text just for the example with some more words some more text just for the example with some more words some more text just for the example with some more words \EndRule and here we add some more text just for the example with some more words some more text just for the example with some more words some more text just for the example and here we add some more text just for the example with some more words some more text just for the example with some more words some more text just for the example

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly in paragraphs with straight text. Do you know of any way to also make it compatible with wrapfig so that I can have a paragraph with a bar in the left margin as well as a small figure on the right with the text wrapped around it?

Comment: @user89082 As my updated answer shows this works with `wrapfig`. If it's not working for you, please update your question with a little example (like te one in my answer) allowing us to reproduce any undesired effects-